# Exception Value : no such table: users_customuser

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I am working on a group django project, and I created a 'customuser' model in an app called 'users'. I have created the model and changed everywhere that referenced django's base user model to reference my user model.

In our app, we want the CustomUser to hold a list of events from the Event Model.

```
#users/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from cal.models import Event
# Create your models here.
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    events_attending = models.ManyToManyField(Event,blank=True)
```

The webapp runs locally, but when I try to log in or register as a user I get the error that there is no such table as customUser.

my migrations are as follows:

```
C:\Users\joe4a\Desktop\Newest\STAJJ>python manage.py showmigrations
admin
 [X] 0001_squashed_0001_initial (1 squashed migrations)
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [X] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
cal
 [X] 0001_initial
cockycal
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
users
 [X] 0001_initial
```

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/

Django Version: 4.1.3
Python Version: 3.10.10
Installed Applications:
['cockycal.apps.CockycalConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'cal',
 'users']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such table: users_customuser) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\Desktop\Newest\STAJJ\users\views.py", line 22, in register
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 205, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 200, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 439, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 129, in _post_clean
    super()._post_clean()
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 498, in _post_clean
    self.validate_unique()
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 507, in validate_unique
    self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1207, in validate_unique
    errors = self._perform_unique_checks(unique_checks)
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1317, in _perform_unique_checks
    if qs.exists():
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1225, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 592, in has_results
    return compiler.has_results()
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1366, in has_results
    return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1398, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\joe4a\.virtualenvs\joe4a-ZLoFqS61\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /register/
Exception Value: no such table: users_customuser
```

Everywhere I can looked up it says all I have to do is migrate and everything will be fine. I have done this, but I am still getting the same error. are there any other reasons this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have to name the file as `models.py` as Django searches for that name in the app. For detailed information on that, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package